# conditional search in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want the search box to search by name or by city based on the appropriate radio button selected. However, the list it displays will contain name-city pair. I tried `ng-if` and `ng-true-value` and `mg-false-value`, but it won't work. Any suggestions?
Here's the code:

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="DemoController">
        Search: <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"/> {{name}}

        <br/><br/>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="search.name" ng-value="search.name" name="search" > By Name </input> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" ng-model="search.city" ng-value="search.city" name="search" > By City </input>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in friends| filter:search.name:friend.name | filter:search.city:friend.city ">{{friend.name}} - {{friend.city}} </li>
        </ul>
        <script>

        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

        demoApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope){
            $scope.friends = [
                {name:'Akshay',city:'Hyderabad'},
                {name:'Peeyush',city:'Madras'},
                {name:'Aditya',city:'Mumbai'}
            ];
        });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to dynamically create the object required by the `filter` filter. Add watches so whenever "By name" is selected, the relevant object will get a property `name`, with the value of the text search; whenever "By city" is selected, the object will get a `city` property instead.

Simplified code:

(HTML)

```
<div>
    Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search.text" />

    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.field" ng-value="'name'" name="sfld">By Name</input>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="search.field" ng-value="'city'" name="sfld">By City</input>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:filterObj">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(JS)

```
$scope.$watch("search.field", function(newval) {
    if( newval ) {
        $scope.filterObj = {};
        $scope.filterObj[$scope.search.field] = $scope.search.text;
    }
    else {
        $scope.filterObj = null;
    }
});
$scope.$watch("search.text", function(newval) {
    if( $scope.search.field ) $scope.filterObj[$scope.search.field] = $scope.search.text;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97Db6/

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned trying to do it with `ng-if`, here one simple way that could work:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="search" value="name" name="search">By Name
<input type="radio" ng-model="search" value="city" name="search">By City

<ul>
  <li ng-if="search == 'name'" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: {name : name}">{{friend.name}}, {{friend.city}}</li>
  <li ng-if="search == 'city'" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: {city : name}">{{friend.name}}, {{friend.city}}</li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/veqpknH9LR25G3e6QDPV